# How to create `this` bound member in object literal?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider the following example of a `this`-bound member in a class.

```
class Foo {
  foo = "foo";
  bar = () => {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const bar1 = (new Foo()).bar;
bar1();
```

This properly logs `foo` to the console.

However, trying to achieve the same in the following object literal fails:

```
const foo = {
  foo: "foo",
  bar() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

const bar2 = foo.bar;
bar2();
```

The error is: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.foo')`

I fully understand why this is happening. So, my question if there is simple way to get the same effect in an object literal.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNHQLzQCJt4CBudaAIzACc9oAKASjwD4UKNh4A7CeEAFMAdCHgBzBgBcAFgEsIw4k3IYAvqg2pufKVVoBGegx6CA7nETMmw6jXJ2Dzctt4Q9xemgzEAXIWICABoKO2YODC43ARExSVkFJUQVCg0tHXd9GgAmemJbWgdabOcgA)

Comment: You lost the `foo` calling context when you put the function into a standalone variable as a callback. Either use `.bind` to set the proper calling context or define a function which *calls* `foo.bar*.

Comment: `foo.bar = foo.bar.bind(foo)`…? Not really any way to do that directly as part of the literal though.

Comment: bind the context in which you want to execute the bar()...... `bar2.bind(foo)()` will help you

Comment: Don't use `this`. For example `const foo = { foo: "foo", bar: () => console.log(foo.foo) }`